# Cascades 3.9 - making a container scroll

Tags: xml, scroll, scrollview, cascade

I am using cascades 3.9, and am having a hard time making a container scroll. This is the code that I have in my visual.

```
<stackLayout id="parent_container" dockLayout.halign="center"
             y="60"
             height="{contentHeight}"
             width="{contentWidth}"
             >

     <gridLayout columns="2" width="{contentWidth}" id="want_scroll">

       <text string="First Name" />
       <text string="First name goes here" font="{@csm.fc.font.h4}" />

       <text string="Last Name" />
       <text string="Last name goes here" font="{@csm.fc.font.h4}" />

       // more items, causing the height to be more than that of the parent

     </gridLayout>
```

I want "want_scroll" to be able to able to scroll as its height is greater than {contentHeight}, the height of "parent_container". I thought wrapping "want_scroll" in scrollView with pointer.scrollable set to true would do the trick. But doing so makes no difference.

```
  <scrollView pointer.scrollable="true">
     <gridLayout columns="2" width="{contentWidth}" id="want_scroll">

       <text string="First Name" />
       <text string="First name goes here" font="{@csm.fc.font.h4}" />

       <text string="Last Name" />
       <text string="Last name goes here" font="{@csm.fc.font.h4}" />

       // more items, causing the height to be more than that of the parent

     </gridLayout>
  </scrollView>
```

How do I add scroll to a simple container?

Note that by scroll, I just want the container to be scrollable, and my question is not regarding showing a scroll bar on the right.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the size of the ScrollView so it knows when to scroll.  Here is an example:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

Page {
     content: Container {
             layout: StackLayout {  }
             ScrollView {
                   content: Container {
                                          layout: StackLayout { }
                                          Label {
                                                text: "Start"
                                          }
                          //snip...  A bunch more labels would go here...

                                         Label {
                                                text: "End"
                                         }
                                  }
                   minWidth: 500
                   minHeight: 1280
           }
      }
}
```